# ARN role for API Gateway to enable logs error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch

I can't enable write access to CloudWatch logs in AWS API Gateway by providing a new IAM Role.

I checked several tutorials, checked everything. Even attached AdministratorAccess policy to my IAM Role and checked that `The identity provider(s) apigateway.amazonaws.com` is a Trusted entity.

But if still fails when I try to enable logs in API Gateway:

> The role ARN does not have required permissions set to API Gateway

Comment: What do you mean - role for API Gateway? perhaps role for Lambda?

Comment: What is the policy of the user who is providing the role to API Gateway? It needs `iam:passRole` permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to IAM and create or select an existing role
2. Attach the AWS managed policy AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs to it, copy the role's ARN
3. Go to API Gateway > Settings and paste the ARN and hit Save
4. Select your API > Stages > pick a stage > Logs/Tracing tab
5. Select 'Enable CloudWatch Logs' and/or 'Log full requests/responses data' as appropriate and hit Save Changes.

Comment: The managed policy `AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs` is granted pretty much full logs access over every log resource in your account. If that isn't acceptable to you (it wasn't for me), then you can use the least privilege approach in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59680654/14367790

Answer (score 17):

I was having this issue today as I was trying to set up a user that I had given those permissions to. Resolved it by going through the "create role" wizard and selecting the API Gateway service which created an IAM arn with the correct permissions.

```
Select your use case
API Gateway
Allows API Gateway to push logs to CloudWatch Logs.
```

Answer (score 7):

For me the following `AWS` configuration fixed this issue.

Edited the "**Trust Relationship**" in the **Role** with the following configuration:

```
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
 {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
    "Service": ["apigateway.amazonaws.com","lambda.amazonaws.com"]
    },
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
  }
 ]
}
```

Edited the **policies** with the following:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "logs:*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is a more detailed description for the policy configuration: [policy description](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/iam-identity-based-access-control-cwl.html)

Answer (score 4):

After much frustration, I followed Alex' advice then gave up for a while.

Eventually, the IAM "stuff" propagated and the "enable logs" requests completely successfully.

Comment: aka: Wait 3 minutes and try again

Answer (score 4):

In case you want to use least privileges for your role, this is the minimum set of permissions to add:

```
CloudWatchRolePolicy: 
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy'
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyName: MyAPIGatewayRolePolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - "logs:CreateLogGroup"
            - "logs:CreateLogStream"
            - "logs:DescribeLogGroups"
            - "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
            Resource:
            - "arn:aws:logs:<account>:log-group:API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_<apiId>/<apiStageName>:*"
            - "arn:aws:logs:<accountId>:log-group:/aws/apigateway/*:*"
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - "logs:PutLogEvents"
            Resource:
            - "arn:aws:logs:<account>:log-group:API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_<apiId>/<apiStageName>:*:*"
            - "arn:aws:logs:<accountId>:log-group:/aws/apigateway/*:*:*"
```

Replacing the parts in `<...>` appropriately.

This is because AWS automatically adds log groups with specific names for you e.g. `/aws/apigateway/welcome` and `API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_<apiId>/<stageId>`. Sadly I can't find any documentation about these so the above is a result of trial and error to get something to save successfully and logs show up!

Comment: Is the region required in the ARN? And what is the difference between `account` and `accountId`?